# Can't click or select an item from javascript dropdown menu using VBA

Tags: javascript, html, vba

As the title suggests, I've found the ClassName of the button I want to click (I think, because the innertext on that ClassName array # gives me the correct text shown on button). Problem is, I'm clicking it but it does nothing.
This is my best attempt, among dozens, but it's not doing anything.

```
For Each i In IE.document.getElementById("typeSelector")
    If i.innerText = "Revenue" Then
        i.Click
        i.FireEvent ("onchange")
        'This click and fireEvent are activated but do nothing.
    End If
Next i
```

'These next ones are Hail Mary's stacked on top of each other to see if I get a reaction out of that damn box. Nada.

```
   Debug.Print IE.document.getElementsByClassName("chzn-single chzn-default")(0).innerText  'Prints "Select an option". I thought clicking this would at least open the drop down menu but still, nothing.
    Debug.Print IE.document.getElementById("typeSelector_chzn_o_14").innerText 'Prints "Revenue". This is the option within the dropdown menu, shown after clicking the menu when manually done.
    IE.document.getElementsByClassName("chzn-single chzn-default")(0).Click
    IE.document.getElementById("typeSelector_chzn_o_14").Click
```

To summarize, I've tried activating the option based on index, clicking the box, clicking the box then clicking the "Revenue" option. The website remains completely unmoved. Should be noted that a succesful click would not update the website, simply highlight the "Revenue" option in the menu, and open up a Date input box.

Comment: that is your problem. it is the Hail Marys .... lol   ...............  put `ie.document` in the `watch window` and examine the resulting object tree

Comment: is your dropdown anything like this ?  ... https://www.exratione.com/2011/12/a-dark-style-for-chosen-selects/

Comment: The hail marys i've just been adding and removing as ideas come up, but removing them doesn't really change anything.

and yes!, the dropdown is exactly like that, even has a similar class name yours:"chzn-single", It also adds stuff/changes name in the html like "chzn-single-with-drop" when clicked.

Comment: This is the HTML of the button I'm having issues with:
https://imgur.com/a/yPyYJ

Comment: please add this to your question, not to a comment ... add the text, not a picture